# In Bash scripting, how is (*) interpreted?

Tags: bash

Given the following partial bash script, how is the first line being interpreted?

Is this a shortcut to the bash command `ls`?

```
l=(*)
for v in ${l[@]}
do 
    echo $v  
done
```

Output:

```
arc
cgi-bin
dist
```

Interestingly, if I type "*" into a bash shell I get the error "bash: arc: command not found", presumably this is related somehow?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No; the parentheses just declare an array in this context. The shell is what expands the `*` glob.

In some more detail,

```
variable=(value1 value2)
```

declares an array with two elements; and the glob `*` expands to the names of all (non-hidden) files in the current directory. If you have files or directories named `arc`, `cgi-bin`, and `dist`, and type

```
*
```

you are attempting to run the command

```
arc cgi-bin dist
```

which of course fails if you don't have a cormand named `arc` anywhere in your `PATH`.

As an aside, `${l[@]}` is incorrect; you definitely want `"${l[@]}"` with double quotes - otherwise you are losing the integrity of any quoted strings in the array (just like `$@` is basically always an error, and needs to be `"$@"`). To just print the array, you don't need a loop;

```
printf '%s\n' "${l[@]}"
```

Answer (score 1):

Try typing `echo *`, that will make things more clear.

By the way, you could have also written:

```
for v in *
do 
    echo "$v"
done
```